# Areas of similar triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $G$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$. A line $a$ though $G$ is constructed such that $a$ is parallel to $AB$ and intersects $AC$ and $BC$ at $M$ and $P$, respectively. I should find the area of $\triangle ABC$ if the area of $\triangle MPC$ is $24$.
>   [image]

I was able to show that $\triangle ABC \sim MPC$. Therefore, $\dfrac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{S_{\triangle MPC}}=\dfrac{AB^2}{MP^2}=k^2$. How to approach the problem further?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Since the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle) $G$ is equal to $\frac{A+B+C}{3}$, it follows that $|CC_1|=3|GC_1|$. Moreover, from your work,
$$\dfrac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{S_{\triangle MPC}}=\dfrac{|CC_1|^2}{|CG_1|^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! How can this help me?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova See my edit.

Comment: But aren't you using the fact that $G$ is the midpoint of $MP$? How can we show this?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Because $C_1$ is the midpoit of $AB$ and the triangles $ABC$ and $MPC$ are similar.

Comment: And how the fact that $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle MPC$ makes $G$ the midpoint of $MP$?

Comment: I have not deleted anything.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova The message was not for you, sorry!

Comment: It's alright. Can you see my question?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova $CC_1$ is the median and $MP$ is parallel to $AB$.

Comment: Yes, I see this. But why $CG$ is the median in $\triangle MPC$. We DON'T KNOW $G$ is the midpoint of $MP$ and I am not sure the fact that $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle MPC$ shows this.

Comment: I don't know how to show this.

Comment: How do we show that $G$ is the midpoint of $MP$?

Comment: $MG/AC_1=GC/C_1G=GP/C_1B$ because $\triangle AC_1C\sim \triangle MGC$ and $\triangle BC_1C\sim \triangle PGC$

Comment: its called homothety lyi